# export liferay user group to OpenLDAP

Tags: liferay, openldap

I configured liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga4 with OpenLDAP. Users are imported into OpenLDAP from liferay. But User group of liferay are not exported into OpenLDAP. Here is my portal-ext.properties:

```
ldap.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory
ldap.server.name=ldapadmin
ldap.auth.enabled=true

ldap.import.enabled=true
ldap.export.enabled=true


ldap.import.on.startup=true
ldap.export.on.startup=true

ldap.export.method.0=group
ldap.export.method.0=user

ldap.password.policy.enabled=true


ldap.base.provider.url.0=ldap://localhost:389
ldap.base.dn.0=dc=test,dc=com
ldap.security.principal.0=cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com
ldap.security.credentials.0=secret

ldap.auth.search.filter.0=(mail=@email_address@)
ldap.import.user.search.filter.0=(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)

ldap.user.mappings.0=userId=uid\nscreenName=cn\nemailAddress=mail\npassword=userPassword\nfirstName=givenName\nlastName=sn



ldap.import.group.search.filter.0=(objectClass=posixGroup)
ldap.group.mappings.0=groupName=cn\ndescription=description\nuser=memberUid
ldap.users.dn.0=ou=people,dc=test,dc=com
ldap.groups.dn.0=ou=groups,dc=test,dc=com

ldap.user.default.object.classes.0=inetOrgPerson, top
ldap.group.default.object.classes.0=posixGroup, top, groupOfUniqueNames,organizationalUnit
```

I have checked by clicking on 'Test LDAP Groups' button I can see around 5 groups which are created in OpenLDAP using OpenLDAP GUI but can't see any group which i create in liferay. Its not exporting User Groups its only exporting users. Please give some solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the keys you use on your portal-ext.properties file are wrong.

In the documentation we can read:

```
#
# Settings for exporting users from the portal to LDAP. This allows a user
# to modify his first name, last name, etc. in the portal and have that
# change pushed to the LDAP server. This setting is not used unless the
# property "ldap.auth.enabled" is set to true.
#
ldap.export.enabled=false

#
# Set this to true if groups and their associations should be exported from
# the portal to LDAP. This setting is not used unless the property
# "ldap.auth.enabled" is set to true.
#
ldap.export.group.enabled=true
```

So you should use:

```
ldap.export.enabled=true
ldap.export.group.enabled=true
```

Comment: I also tried this. But this is also not exporting user groups.

Comment: Can you check if there is not a missing required attribute (depending on your LDAP schema) in the ldap.group.mappings.0 key ?

Do you have log on your LDAP server ?

Comment: I have checked, there is no missing required attribute.